# How to convert word docx or doc to HTML page without changing the style and fonts in PHP?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pdf, docx

I have tried with many given solutions,but we need the exact conversion in PHP.
Sample code: Its working but style and right left align are missing, it is not giving the actual html conversion.

```
include('./docx_reader.php');

$doc = new Docx_reader();
$doc->setFile('./sample.docx');

if(!$doc->get_errors()) {

$html = $doc->to_html();
$plain_text = $doc->to_plain_text();
echo "HTML is".$html;

$filename="abc.html"; // whatever name you want.
$myfile = fopen($filename, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
//$txt =  httpPost(<url>, ""); //<url> replace by url you want.
fwrite($myfile, $html);

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    //echo "The file $filename exists";
    echo "File Created";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
fclose($myfile);
```

Please update the solution sample codes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a view file in `Codeigniter` which has HTML content and you want it as HTML content in a php variable?

Comment: Thank you. But have a word file. we need to convert that file to HTML

Comment: Try the [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) library, see example [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1184)